# Prove that $\text{ord}_{2^k}5=2^{k-2}$ where $k$ is any integer $\geq3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\text{ord}_{2^k}5=2^{k-2}$ where $k$ is any integer $\geq3$.

I am using the fact that for any odd integer $a$ and $k\geq3$, $a^{2^{k-2}}\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }2^k)$.

So, by the definition $\text{ord}_{2^k}5$ is the least positive integer $x$ such that $5^x\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }2^k)$. And since 5 is odd, then $5^{2^{k-2}}\equiv1\text{ }(\text{mod }2^k)$ by the fact above.

But I am struggling to show that $2^{k-2}$ is the least integer. Any theorems or facts that I can use?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can prove it by induction on $k$.

More precisely, one proves that for any $k\ge 3$, we can write
\begin{equation}5^{2^{k-2}}=1+n_k\cdot 2^k, \quad n_k\enspace\text{odd.}\tag{1}\end{equation}

*Initialisation* is trivially satisfied (for $n=3$, it means $5 ^2=1+3\cdot 8$).

*Inductive step:* suppose for some $k\ge 3$, $\;(1)$ is satisfied. Then
$$5^{2^{k-1}}=\Bigl(5^{2^{\scriptstyle k-2}}\Bigr)^2=\bigl(1+n_k\cdot 2^k\bigr)^2=1+n_k2^{k+1}+n_k^2\mkern1mu2^{2k}=1+n_k(1+n_k2^{k-1})2^{k+1}.$$
This proves the inductive step, as $\;n_k(1+n_k2^{k-1})$ is odd.

Relation $(1)$ proves the order is $2^{k-2}$.

Indeed, if for some $k$ it were less, it would be  $2^{k-i}$, $i\ge3$, so we would have $\;5^{2^{k-3}}=1+n\cdot 2^k$. However this would imply
$$5^{2^{k-2}}=(1+n\cdot 2^k)^2=1+(2n+n^22^k)2^k$$
and the coefficient $2n+n^22^k$ would be even, not odd.

Comment: thanks. But what does it have to do with order? I mean how can we show it is the least?

Comment: @user71346: I've added some details. Is that clearer?