# Prove that the order of $5$ mod $2^k$ is equal to $2^{k-2}$ where k is any integer greater than or equal to 3.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, congruences, integers

Here is a proof: [Prove that $\text{ord}_{2^k}5=2^{k-2}$ where $k$ is any integer $\geq3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486648/prove-that-textord-2k5-2k-2-where-k-is-any-integer-geq3)

I do understand that $n_k$ is odd but how does that relate to the order of 5 mod $2^k$? Why does that show that $2^{k-2}$ is the least positive integer stastifying the required property? Thanks.

Comment: Bernard explains that if some smaller number than $2^{k-2}$ is the order of $5$ modulo $2^k$, then we have that 5^{2^{k-2}} = 1 + $ even number $\cdot 2^k$, which is not possible, by the induction proof.

Comment: But he only proved that $2^{k-3}$ cannot be the order of 5. What about smaller cases such as $2^{k-i}$ where i is greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: We have that the order is a divisor of $2^{k-2}$. Now if some $2^{t}$, where $t<k-3$ is the order of $5$, then we have that $5^{2^{k-3}} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^k}$, as the order of $5$ divides $2^{k-3}$. But this is impossible.

Comment: Well yeah, but also

$$5^{2^{k-3}} \equiv 5^{2^{t} \cdot 2^{k-3-t}} \equiv (5^{2^{t}})^{2^{k-3-t}} \equiv 1^{2^{k-3-t}} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^k}$$

Answer (score 1):

By Lifting the Exponent lemma $v_2 (5^{2^n} -1 ) = v_2(5-1)+v_2 (2^n) = n+2$

Hence the highest exponent of $2$ that divides $5^{2^{k-2}}-1$ is $k$.

Conversely, the order of $5$ mod $2^k$ will therefore be $2^{k-2}$